# Test whether PHP is correctly installed on my Mac

Tags: macos, installation, apache-http-server, php, localhost

I use Homebrew to installed the php 5.6, I followed the guide from Homebrew to enable Apache and PHP (such as uncommenting the `httpd.conf` file), then I can successfully access to `http://localhost/` and it shows "It works" page.

However, I was trying to access to `http://localhost/~yang` where the `yang` is my username. I created a Sites folder inside my home folder, tried to access to `http://localhost/~yang/`, however it prompted 404 error.

I also tried to copy a PHP file called `index.php` into the Sites folder, and manually access to `http://localhost/~yang/index.php`, It still shows 404 error.

I am not sure in which step I did wrong.

Comment: Find where Apache has its webserver root. I.e. where localhost is on your file system and make your new directory under that, not under /home  FI it is not clear where from your Apache config files, you could search your drives for that index.php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your /home directory you need to edit your `httpd.conf` and enable `UserDir`
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html